# Euclid's Lemma using FToA

Tags: real-analysis, prime-numbers

I would really appreciate some help understanding the following passage from my Real Analysis text. I have a professor who uses inquiry based learning, which basically means we all stare at each other for a couple hours until giving up.

> An important fact that we will need comes from the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. Suppose we have positive integers *a*, *b*, and *d* such that *d|ab* and *d* is relatively prime to *a*. Let *ab=de*. Since *a* and *d* are relatively prime, the prime factors of *a* are all distinct from those of *d*. Now apply the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic to *ab* and *de* to conclude that, if *p* is prime and *p^k|d*, then *p^k|b*. It follows that *d|b*. Fill in the details to prove the following:
>
> *If a, b, and d are integers such that d|ab and d and a are relatively prime, then d|b*

I understand that via FToA, *d* and *b* must share some primes since *a* and *d* do not. I'm missing where it makes the leap from that factor *p^k|d* and *p^k|b* then *d|b*. The best we came up with in class is that the entirety of *d* is contained  within *b*, but I don't see how that is always true.

Comment: Hi Frustrated: $a=p_1^{n_1}…..p_k^{n_k}$ ; $b=q_1^{m_1}…..q_s^{m_s}$ and the prime factors of $d$ are all distinct of the $p_i^{n_i}$ by hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is that since $a$ and $d$ are relatively prime, not only do $b$ and $d$ share some primes, but $b$ must have all the primes that $d$ does. This is because the prime factorization of $d$ is a subset of the prime factorization of $ab$. Thus, if the prime factorization of $d$ contains some prime $p$ $k$ times, $ab$ must also contain that prime $k$ times. Since $a$ does not, it must be in $b$.